# Gallery images visible based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I need a photography gallery to display in 3 rows, each row showing different number of images. Not all images have the same width. When the screen resizes I want more images to show, but in the same ratio (grow to 3/5/4, 4/6/5, etc...). The ratio should be like this (brackets represent an image):

```
[][]
[][][][]
[][][]
```

[Visual example here.](http://elusiveform.com/example.jpg)

It was partly working except for the offset. I tried to write an offset loop, and now it's not working at all. Here is the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.gallery').wrap('<div class="gal-wrapper" />');
  resizeGallery("#gallery-1",2);
  resizeGallery("#gallery-2",4);
  resizeGallery("#gallery-3",3);
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  resizeGallery("#gallery-1",2);
  resizeGallery("#gallery-2",4);
  resizeGallery("#gallery-3",3);
});

function resizeGallery(gall, initpos){
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var accum_width = 0;
var final_width = accum_width;
var offset = initpos;
var wW = jQuery(window).width()-jQuery("#nav").width();

while(accum_width < wW){

    var new_width = jQuery(gall).find("img.attachment-medium:eq("+x+")").width();
    if((accum_width + new_width) > wW){
        break;
    }else{
        accum_width += new_width+4;
    }
    x++;
}
/* worked partly to this point... onto the offset! */ 
while(y < offset){
    var subtract_width = jQuery(gall).find("img.attachment-medium:eq("+x+")").width();
    final_width -= subtract_width+4;
    y++;
    x--;
}


jQuery(gall).parent().width(final_width);
}
</script>
```

[Here is a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Urjgn/).

Comment: By same ratio do you mean the next screen size is 4/8/6 images or 3/5/4, or another?

Comment: When enough room was avaiable it'd grow to 3/5/4, 4/6/5, etc.

Comment: Is stackoverflow sick of gallery questions?

Comment: Have a patience and provide a fiddle if you can at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Urjgn/

If you remove the offset while loop, change the last line from  ~~~.width(final_width);

to

~~~~.width(accum_width);

then yuo'll see it partially working.

Comment: @drrobotnik, just a snippet of code out of any context and not testable is quite hard to correct... it looks our comments crossed!

Answer (score 0):

[Your working JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CobaltBlueDW/Urjgn/1/)

In case That fiddle link doesn't work...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.gallery').wrap('<div class="gal-wrapper" />');
    var picCount = resizeGallery("#gallery-2", Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    resizeGallery("#gallery-3", picCount-1);
    resizeGallery("#gallery-1", picCount-2);
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var picCount = resizeGallery("#gallery-2", Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    resizeGallery("#gallery-3", picCount-1);
    resizeGallery("#gallery-1", picCount-2);
});

function resizeGallery(gall, picCount) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var accum_width = 0;
    var wW = jQuery(window).width() - jQuery("#nav").width();

    while (accum_width < wW && x < picCount) {

        var new_width = jQuery(gall).find("img.attachment-medium:eq(" + x + ")").width();
        if ((accum_width + new_width) > wW) {
            break;
        } else {
            accum_width += new_width + 4;
        }
        x++;
    }

    jQuery(gall).parent().width(accum_width);

    return x;
}
```